# How to write a code to display output value in every 60 minutes using panda python using csv file

Tags: python, pandas, time, lstm

I have temperature in a csv file. My file is updated with time . I have loaded this data to a pandas DataFrame. What I want to do is predict temperature value in next 60 minutes.

I changed the start time into 0 minutes.

After changed the start time into 0 minutes then I write the code for to display time in every 60 minutes.

```
date                  time   temp   humidity  wind                     
2018-10-03 06:00:00    0.0    63       0        0
2018-10-03 07:00:00   60.0    63       0        2
2018-10-03 08:00:00   120.0   104      11       0
2018-10-03 09:00:00   180.0   93       0        50
2018-10-03 10:00:00   240.0   177      0        2
2018-10-03 11:00:00   300.0   133      0        0
2018-10-03 12:00:00   360.0   70       0        0
2018-10-03 13:45:00   465.0   83       0        60
2018-10-03 15:00:00  540.0    127      0        50
2018-10-03 16:00:00  600.0    205      0        0
2018-10-03 17:00:00  660.0    298      0        0
2018-10-03 18:00:00  720.0    234      0        0
2018-10-03 19:00:00  780.0    148      0        20
2018-10-03 20:00:00  840.0    135      0        0
2018-10-03 21:30:00  930.0    100      0        50
2018-10-04 06:00:00    0.0    166      0        0
2018-10-04 07:00:00   60.0     0       0        0
```

After that I wrote the code for next output temperature value. mean my first output is 63 (temp) at 60 minutes.

```
time(t)        temp     humidity   wind     output(temp )(t+60)
 0              63        0          0         63
 60             63        0          2         104
```

Like this it should be run.

What I am trying to do is to display my output (next temperature value ) value in every 60 minutes. inputs will be added same as csv file . But output should be display in every 60 minutes.

I wrote the code for that. But It is not properly displaying my output.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

my code:

```
import datetime
data = pd.read_csv('data6.csv' , sep=',')
print(data)
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
lastday = data.loc[0, 'date']
def convert_time(x):
  global lastday
  if x.date() == lastday.date():
    tm = x - lastday
    return tm.total_seconds()/60
else:
    lastday = x
    return 0

data['time'] = data['date'].apply(convert_time)
data.set_index('date', inplace=True)


data = data.values

X = 1
n_out = 1

x,y=list(),list()
start =0

for _ in range(len(data)):
  in_end = start+X
out_end= in_end + n_out
if out_end < len(data):
    x_input = data[start:in_end]
    x.append(x_input)

    while y.append(data[in_end:out_end,1]):
        if data['time'] <= 60:
            print(y)
            data['time']+=1
start +=1

 x = np.asanyarray(x)
 y = np.asanyarray(y)
```

my output:

```
[[ 63.][104.][ 93.][177.][133.][ 70.][ 83.][127.][205.][298.][234.][148.[135.][100.][166.]]
```

But here the issue came that

After 12:00:00 I measured the value at 13:45. So after 12:00:00 my output is displaying according to the 13:45 (mean 465 minute) value. But I want to get my output in every 60 min , if no value in that time I want to put it as 0 at that time.

What I want to write for output is

```
time         temp     humidity    wind
360          70        0           0
420          0         0           0
480          0         0           0
```

inputs should be added like this

```
 time        temp  humidity  wind
 0 min        63     0         0 
 0-60 min     63     0         2
    :
    :
```

Then here at

```
 12:00:00 ; 13:00:00
```

inputs :

```
 time (360:420 min )  70  0  0
 time (420:480 min)   83  0  0
```

This is the method that I am trying to do .But it didn't come nicely according to my code.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

csv file:
 [My csv file.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KsAtm0vSsBfOL8z42UAPAwljaO1-DSKfdD9lSu3lv80/edit#gid=35707506)

Using resampling method, output:

[image]

Then the output:

Output after resampling:

[image]

Comment: Try using [pandas.DataFrame.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

Comment: @run-out Yes I tried that method but the output is not coming what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following approach:

```
import pandas as pd

# 1.txt contains data from the question with comma as a separator
df = pd.read_csv('1.txt', parse_dates=[0])
# add column with date only
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.date

# main processing flow applied to every date
def f(a):
    # temperature
    b = a['temp']
    # date & time
    b.index = a['date']
    # resampling with 5 min step
    c = b.resample('5T').apply(lambda x: x[0] if x.count() > 0 else None)
    # linear interpolation
    d = c.interpolate('linear')
    # resampling with 1 hour step
    e = d.resample('1H').apply(lambda x: x[0])
    return e

# group by date and apply f() to every group, dfg is a pandas series
dfg = df.groupby('day').apply(lambda x: f(x)).droplevel(0)
```

`dfg` is:

```
date
2018-10-03 06:00:00     63.000000
2018-10-03 07:00:00     63.000000
2018-10-03 08:00:00    104.000000
2018-10-03 09:00:00     93.000000
2018-10-03 10:00:00    177.000000
2018-10-03 11:00:00    133.000000
2018-10-03 12:00:00     70.000000
2018-10-03 13:00:00     77.428571
2018-10-03 14:00:00     91.800000
2018-10-03 15:00:00    127.000000
2018-10-03 16:00:00    205.000000
2018-10-03 17:00:00    298.000000
2018-10-03 18:00:00    234.000000
2018-10-03 19:00:00    148.000000
2018-10-03 20:00:00    135.000000
2018-10-03 21:00:00    111.666667
2018-10-04 06:00:00    166.000000
2018-10-04 07:00:00      0.000000
Name: temp, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In your code you assume only temp. But I want to predict value with these three inputs and predict the temperature value. So here I guess this is non linear method and I tried to predict value using LSTM. Then what I have to change according to your code.

Comment: To perform this calcualtion for 3 columns replace `a['temp']` with `a[['temp', 'humidity', 'wind']]`.

Comment: So here interpolate with linear or nonlinear? If I want to use LSTM model then what I have to change according to your code?

Comment: @awa The code uses simple linear interpolation for resampling data with 1 hour step and has nothing in common with any machine learning method. Because `pandas` is all about handling tables. The code may be used as a part of data preparation before training models but that's it. You can't just modify the code since it's not about ML.

Comment: okay I understood what you are saying. Thank you for replying me.

Comment: I got an error while using your code. the error is "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'droplevel'

Comment: @awa `droplevel(...)` means drop level of multiindex. So your dataframe has regular index not multiindex. You may just omit `.droplevel(...)` and check what you get. Probably you have modified the code/data somehow or you use old `pandas` version.

Comment: I just omit .droplevel(..) ,then the code is working. Yes I changed the code that putting "a[['temp', 'humidity', 'wind']]"